# How do I scroll to the bottom of a dynamic ul to which I append data [using jquery, socket.io in code]

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, node.js, socket.io

I have tried various failed methods for these by other similar questions. Hopefully, y'all can help me. I need help in the part where socket receives an event. Please comment if you require any more details from me

```
  <body>
    <ul id="messages"></ul>
    <form id="sendform" action="">
      <input id="m" autocomplete="on" /><button>Send</button>
    </form>

        <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(function(){
                var socket = io();
    //          var ready = false;
                var nick;
                while(nick=='' || nick==null)
                    nick = prompt('Enter nick : ');

                socket.emit("join", nick);

                $('#m').focus();
            $("#sendform").submit(function(){
                    if($('#m').val()=='')
                        return false;
              socket.emit('chat message',$('#m').val());
                    $('#m').val('');
              return false;
            });

                socket.on("update",function(msg){
                    $('#messages').append('<li id="update" >'+ msg);
                });
                socket.on('chat message', function(nick,msg){
                    $('#messages').append("<li> <strong>" + nick + "</strong> : " + msg)  ;
                        $('ul, html').css("scrollTop", $("#messages li:last").offset().top);
                });
            });

        </script>
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can try this, provided `#messages` is the scroll-able area in your DOM.

```
$("#messages").animate({scrollTop: $('#messages').prop("scrollHeight")}, 1000);
```

Comment: may i trouble you further to explain the code? how does scrolltop understand where the bottom of my ul is?

Comment: The `$('#messages').prop("scrollHeight")` part is where that is calculated, scrollHeight is the vertical scrollable dimension.

Answer (score -1):

wrap the ul.messages in a div with a class ="msg-con"

```
<div class="msg-con">
 <ul class="messages">
  <li>messages</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

now add the javascript

```
socket.on('chat message',function(){

var msgDiv = document.getElementById('msg-con');
        msgDiv.scrollTop = msgDiv.scrollHeight;

});
```

hope this works...